# C# - How to use dynamic linq to create linq to XML queries

Tags: c#, linq, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml, dynamic-linq

I have a requirement where the users will provide conditional statements as a string from a UI, which I have to incorporate in my LINQ to XML queries. 
I referred this site for dynamic linq queries But it only specifies LINQ to SQL and not LINQ to XML, which is what i need

https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

I tried editing this to fit my requirement, but it doesnt seem to work.

```
    string xml = @"
               <Results>
                    <Result>
                        <Name>John</Name>
                        <Phone>110</Phone>
                        <Location>USA</Location>
                    </Result>
                    <Result>
                        <Name>Mary</Name>
                        <Phone>120</Phone>
                        <Location>UK</Location>
                    </Result>
                    <Result>
                        <Name>John</Name>
                        <Phone>130</Phone>
                        <Location>Canada</Location>
                    </Result>
              </Results>
       ";

        XElement results = XElement.Parse(xml);
        var query = results.Elements("Result")
                           .AsQueryable().
                           .OrderBy("Element(XName.Get(\"Name\")).Value 
                            ascending, Element(XName.Get(\"Phone\")).Value ascending");


        foreach (var i in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
```

When this code runs, I get the error

```
System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException' occurred in System.Linq.Dynamic.dll 
Additional information: No property or field XName' exists in type 'XElement'
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Im trying to achieve the dynamic LINQ query. I want the statement inside the where clause to be picked up from an user input. The statement will be passed as a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
XElement results = XElement.Parse(xml);
var query = results.Elements("Result").AsQueryable().OrderBy(x=>x.Element("Name").Value).ThenBy(x=>x.Element("Phone").Value);
```

Fluent syntax and query syntax  are different things, don't mix them up.

Comment: Im trying to  achieve the dynamic LINQ query. I want the statement inside the where clause to be picked up from an user input. The statement will be passed as a string.